# Unix command to find a string in a file and print only the pattern text with the string

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I want only to print the matching pattern if the pattern has a specific string using unix commands.

For example: find `25487` in the `xyz.txt` file and print the text in between `please` and `till here` from the `xyz.txt` file to a new file.

xyz.txt file...

```
.........
..
....
...

please print 25487 this
sadf
sdfa
sdfasgda
till here

.....
.........
..

please print 45862 this
qret
ret
ASF
H
till here
.........
..
....
...
```

And finally print only

```
please print 25487 this
sadf
sdfa
sdfasgda
till here
```

Comment: actually im trying to compare two years of files after creating the files like this... so i can get the missing or added content in between the pattern...

Comment: think you don't have any problem with grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` can do this very easily.

```
 sed -n '/25487/, /till here/ p'
```

**Test**

```
$ sed -n '/25487/, /till here/ p' input
please print 25487 this
sadf
sdfa
sdfasgda
till here
```

**What it does?**

- `-n` suppresses the printing of pattern space
- `'/25487/, /till here/` Address range. Selects all lines between the two patterns and take the action following.

  Here it selects lines between `25487` and `till here`
- `p` prints the pattern space.

Comment: But what if `25487` present at the middle?

Comment: just assuming that `till here` is not on the same line as `25487` (what you force also using the `^` for the second pattern.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Works if `25487` is in ths same line only. Will edit if there is some chagens

Comment: @NeronLeVelu will remove the anchor to make it more specific

Comment: guys please see this and tell me whats wrong im doing...
for qwerty in `awk ' { print $1 }' done.txt`     
do
sed -n "/$qwerty/,/end{center}/p" Summary.txt >> lol3.txt
done

Comment: @checkmate You will have to escape the `}` and `{`

Comment: the thing is when i do : for qwerty in `awk ' {print $1}' done.txt` do sed -n '/'"$qwerty"'/,/end{center}/p' Summary.txt >> Newii.txt done
it does not work............ yet when i just try with the manual... : sed -n '/25487/, /end{center}/ p' it works fine and gives the output

Comment: @checkmate if you want to  expands shell variable in sed then `sed -n "/$qwerty/,/end{center}/p" Summary.txt ` I think you can very well get rid of the awk part but am not sure of what you want exactly

Comment: It is that i have numbers in one text file and there is another file with description for each number. i need to get only the descriptions following the given numbers in the file. so from awk i get each line in the file assign it to a variable "qwerty" and look it on the description file and then get the relevent description to a new file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use grep.

```
$ grep -oPz '(?s)\bplease\b.*?25487.*?\btill here\b' file
please print 25487 this
sadf
sdfa
sdfasgda
till here
```

`(?s)` DOTALL modifier which makes dot in your regex to match newline characters also. By default dot won't match line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the context option in `grep` to get the lines after the current line. The `-A` option will give you what you want, just specify how many lines you want after the current line, so just do:

```
grep -A 4 25487 xyz.txt > newfile.txt
```

`-A 4` will match the 4 lines after the current matching line. If you wanted the 4 lines before you'd use `-B` and if you want before and after the current line you'd use `-C`.

Comment: But of course, that's only possible if you know exactly how many lines of trailing context to print.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `awk`

```
awk '/25487/,/till here/' xyz.txt
please print 25487 this
sadf
sdfa
sdfasgda
till here
```

This is better if you have other test to do too:

```
awk '/25487/{f=1} f; /till here/{f=0}' xyz.txt
```

or this

```
awk '/25487/{f=1} /till here/{f=0;print} f' xyz.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/please/,/till here/!d
     H
     /till here/!b
     s/.*//
     x
     /25487/!d
     s/.//p' YourFile
```

- don't care line out of section starting with `please` and ending with `till here` and cycle (go to next line entry)
- store the line
- if not line with `till here`, cycle
- empty current line
- exchange with buffer content
- if no `25847` inside, delete and cycle
- remove first char (an extra new line) and print, than cycle